Spotfire and Regex- Extracting Several Values Stored in One Column
I'm needing some help with a RegEx expression that can split some of the values of one column into multiple columns of data. The background on this issue is that this dataset was pulled from a MySQL source that had this particular column stored as a json column, but json columns do not come into Spotfire, so I had to do a cast function just to bring it in.
Let's call this column [Many Values]. Column [Many Values] stores the same information format for all rows, but the data values in it can be different from row to row. As an example, this is what [Many Values] looks like:
[Many Values]
Row 1:  {"ValueA":100,"ValueB":50,"ValueC":20,"ValueD":0.09,"ValueE":108.5...}
Row 2:  {"ValueA":45,"ValueB":20,"ValueC":76,"ValueD":10.20,"ValueE":null...}
Row 3:  {"ValueA":-10,"ValueB":200,"ValueC":40,"ValueD":27.1666,"ValueE":61.23...}
[Many Values] has a lot of information stored in it, but I'd like to have a calculated column (or multiple calculated columns) that will look something like this for Row 1:
[ValueA Extracted]: 100
[ValueB Extracted]: 50
[ValueC Extracted]: 20
...
Is there a good RegEx expression that I can use to pick out what values I need and pair them with the numbers that belong? Or should I consider a different approach? Thanks for the help!

are there a fixed number of columns A,B,C encoded in [Many Values]?

You should start with https://www.google.com/search?q=spotfire+ingest+json. there is no reason to parse JSON with regex...

Yes- there is a specific number of fixed columns in [Many Values]

MonkeyZeus- I loaded this data in via MySQL using the On-Demand setting and I couldn't bring it over with the column being in the JSON form, so I did a cast on it and it made a varchar character type column. Using this provided link, I'm not seeing how it could be brought in otherwise. I got tons of errors and the only way it would even come through was by casting the column via the SQL query.

This might want to be automated with some scripting, depending on how many columns there are to be extracted.
I have taken your 3 rows and calculated the following columns:
Json2: RXReplace([Json_string],"(\\{|\\})","","g")

Where [Json_string] is the original column with the JSON. This removes the {}.
Then for each column in the string (there were A B C D and E) I have created a calculated column like:
Real(RXReplace(Split([Json2],",",1),'"ValueA":','','g'))

This is for column A. For B you use 2 instead of 1, and ValueB instead of ValueA. For C you use 3 and ValueC. Etc.
The Real() takes automatically care of the nulls.

This worked perfectly. Really appreciate the time and effort that went into this answer! You're always very helpful, wish I had you on speed dial lol! Thanks Gaia!
